# DIfferences when using counters

Tags: translation

How do i say the following (sorry I don't know how to get hiragana on a computer im just going to use romaji)

Ken-san read 100 pages of a book.
Ken-san read a 100 page book (a book that has 100 pages).
Ken-san read a 100 books (100 individiual books).

I'm thinking that it'll go something like Kensan wa hon no hyaku peeji o yomimasu for the first one, with the second one being ken-san wa hyaku peeji no hon o yomimasu, and the third is just kensan wa hyakusatsu (?) hon o yomimasu

Comment: Translation requests are off-topic; do you have any guess as to how these might translate, or what research have you done on which counters are used for pages and books?

Comment: Resolving the 'not being able to get hiragana on a computer' issue seems like it should be deserving of greater priority.

Comment: oh yea. I'm thinking that it'll go something like Kensan wa hon no hyaku peeji o yomimasu for the first one, with the second one being ken-san wa hyaku peeji no hon o yomimasu, and the third is just kensan wa hyakusatsu (?) hon o yomimasu

Comment: @AbdullahImad Yes, please add those sentences to your main text so that let people know you're asking a decent question.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are talking about the sentences in the past tense, so you have to say *yomima**shita*** instead of *yomima**su***.

> (1)
> (1E) Ken-san read 100 pages of the book.
> (1J) Kensan wa hon no hyaku peeji o yomimashita.

Answer for (1):

- (1J-1) ケンさんは本{ほん}の100ページを読｛よ｝みました。
- (1J-2) ケンさんは本{ほん}の100ページ目｛め｝を読｛よ｝みました。
- (1E-2) *Ken-san read the 100th page of the book.*
- (1J-3) ケンさんは本{ほん}を100ページ読｛よ｝みました。
- (1J-4) ケンさんは**その**本{ほん}を100ページ読｛よ｝みました。

(1J) could be written as (1J-1) with *hiragana*s and *kanji*s.
(1J) is not correct because it sounds like (1J-2) or (1E-2). The correct sentence in Japanese for (1E) is like (1J-3). As "**the** book" is used in (1E), (1J-4) is better than (1J-3).

> (2)
> (2E) Ken-san read a 100 page book.
> (2J) ken-san wa hyaku peeji no hon o yomimashita.

Answer for (2):

- (2J-1) ケンさんは100ページの本{ほん}を読｛よ｝みました。

(2J) could be written as (2J-1) with *hiragana*s and *kanji*s.
(2J) is correct.

> (3)
> (3E) Ken-san read a 100 books.
> (3J) kensan wa hyakusatsu hon o yomimashita.

Answer for (3):

- (3J-1) ケンさんは100冊｛さつ｝本を読｛よ｝みました。
- (3J-2) ケンさんは本{ほん}を100冊｛さつ｝読｛よ｝みました。

(3J) could be written as (3J-1) with *hiragana*s and *kanji*s.
(3J) is correct.
By the way, I usually say like (3J-2) for (3E).

## BONUS for advanced learners

> (bonus-e) Ken-san reads a 100 page book.
> (bonus-j1) ken-san wa hyaku peeji no hon o yomimasu.
> (bonus-j2) ケンさんは100ページの本{ほん}を読｛よ｝みます。

(bonus-j1) and (bonus-j2) are sentences in the present tense of ones written in (2).

They have different meanings from (bonus-e) as follows.

- (bonus-j3) ケンさんは毎日｛まいにち｝100ページの本｛ほん｝を読｛よ｝みます。 *It is Ken-san's custom to read a hundred page book everyday.* or *Ken-san reads a hundred page book everyday.*
- (bonus-j4) ケンさんはこれから100ページの本｛ほん｝を読｛よ｝もうとしています。
  *Ken-san is going to read a hundred page book.*
- (bonus-j5) ケンさんは100ページの本｛ほん｝を好｛この｝んで読｛よ｝みます。
  *Ken-san prefers to read a hundred page book.* or *Ken-san reads only a hundred page book.*

The interpretation of (bonus-J5) may sound strange, but syntactically, it is the same as "ケンさんは探偵小説｛たんていしょうせつ｝を読｛よ｝みます。 *Ken-san prefers to read detective stories*" or "ケンさんは旅行雑誌{りょこうざっし}を読｛よ｝みます。 *Ken-san prefers to read travel magazines*", so it is not strange.

Answer (score 0):

The first one, "hon no hyaku peeji o yomimasu", means "read page 100 of the book". "Read 100 pages of a book" is "hon o hyaku peeji yomimasu/hyaku peeji hon o yomimasu" (counters with no particle can either precede or follow nouns, and it's generally more natural for the counter to follow than to precede.)

The others are correct. Hyakusatsu doesn't need a particle in this case.